# Rotate cubetexture in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, skybox

I got this cubetexture in Three.js. Say I want to rotate the cubeTexture itself 180 degrees. I know I can do this by rotating the camera but I want to rotate the texture itself and not the camera. How can I achieve this?

I want to rotate the x axis of the cubeTexture causing it to display the opposite side. Something like `texture.flipX = true;` would be handy.

https://codepen.io/haangglide/pen/GRZPqaw

```
var camera, scene, box, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const texture = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
        .setCrossOrigin('')     .setPath('https://alca.tv/static/codepen/pens/common/SwedishRoyalCastle/').load(['px.jpg', 'nx.jpg', 'py.jpg', 'ny.jpg', 'pz.jpg', 'nz.jpg']);
    
    scene.background = texture;

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color('skyblue') });
    box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(box);
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    scene.add(camera);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

According to the following discussions it does not seem easy or even possible to do what you ask with ThreeJS, but in the first link it does mention that it may be possible with BabylonJS.

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/rotate-a-scenes-background-skybox-texture/12199
https://discourse.threejs.o9rg/t/rotate-a-scenes-background/3928/15

**Original answer:**

You didn't say which axis so I will just use the Y axis. I am also using 45 degrees instead of 180 so you can see it is working.

```js
var camera, scene, box, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const texture = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
        .setCrossOrigin('')     .setPath('https://alca.tv/static/codepen/pens/common/SwedishRoyalCastle/').load(['px.jpg', 'nx.jpg', 'py.jpg', 'ny.jpg', 'pz.jpg', 'nz.jpg']);
    
    scene.background = texture;
    
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color('skyblue') });
    box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    
    ///
    ///
    ///
    ///////////////////////////////
    //since threejs uses radians, you will need a function to get radians from degrees
    function getRadians(degrees) {
      return Math.PI / 180 * degrees;
    }
    
    //using rotation.set(x, y, z)
    box.rotation.set(0, getRadians(45), 0);
    
    //directly setting the rotations
    box.rotation.y = getRadians(45);
    ///////////////////////////////
    ///
    ///
    ///
    
    scene.add(box);
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    scene.add(camera);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear.  I want to rotate the cubeTexture causing it to display the opposite side. This only rotates the cube

Comment: You want to rotate the the texture but not the mesh?